# Как применяются правила из различных ruleset'ов в eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

Пробую различные конфиг-файлы .eslintrc.js в проекте и вот какой вопрос у меня возник.

В секции extends как работает порядок подключения и что будет с правилами, которые конфликтуют друг с другом? Допустим у меня есть не какой-то стандартный набор правил типа

```
extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', 'airbnb-base'],
```

а сборная солянка из большого числа пакетов правил взятых с какой-нибудь статьи ([вот тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/417841/) например большая пачка).

Вряд ли же авторы проверяли свои правила на совместимость друг с другом, возможно что будут какие-то противоречащие друг другу правила в разных пакетах. Применится первое правило? Последнее? Оба применятся и сразу будет видно два друг другу противоположных сообщения типа "должны быть одинарные кавычки"/"должны быть двойные кавычки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: применяется последнее правило.**

Согласно [документации](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files),

Конфиг-файл может расширять базовые конфигурации с помощью свойства `extends`, которое может быть:

- строкой (имя базовой конфигурации)
- массивом строк: каждая следующая конфигурация наследуется от предыдущей

Свойство `rules` позволяет изменять или расширять базовую конфигурацию следующими способами:

- Добавить дополнительные правила (не присутствующие в базовой конфигурации)
- Изменить строгость (severity) правила, унаследованного от базовой конфигурации (без изменения параметров правила). Например:

  - Базовая конфигурация: `"eqeqeq": ["error", "allow-null"]`
  - Конфигурация, расширяющая базовую: `"eqeqeq": "warn"`
  - Результат: `"eqeqeq": ["warn", "allow-null"]`
- Переопределить правило из базовой конфигурации. Например:

  - Базовая конфигурация: `"quotes": ["error", "single", "avoid-escape"]`
  - Конфигурация, расширяющая базовую: `"quotes": ["error", "single"]`
  - Результат: `"quotes": ["error", "single"]`